# Delete multiple files while only keeping the newest files with many different file names

Tags: c#, file-management

I have a folder with many different filenames that follow the format of (filename.extension.indexnumber) I want to keep the 3 newest files of each filename and delete the rest. Here is the code that I have used to compile the list of files.

```
string dir = Convert.ToString(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
int asm = comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
int prt = comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1;
int drw = comboBox3.SelectedIndex + 1;

var assembliesToBeDeleted = (from a in di.GetFiles("*.asm.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        orderby a.LastWriteTime descending, a.Name ascending
        select a).ToArray();

foreach (var assembly in assembliesToBeDeleted)
{
    //assembly.Delete();
}
```

The list I end up with looks like this:

```
scumbox_ga.asm.338
scumbox_ga.asm.337
manway_nozzle.asm.3
inputcheck.asm.452
inputcheck.asm.451
inputcheck.asm.450
inputcheck.asm.449
inputcheck.asm.448
inputcheck.asm.447
cover_w_holes.asm.10
cls_halftank.asm.426
cls_halftank.asm.425
cls_half_final.asm.423
cls_half_final.asm.422
cls_half_final.asm.421
cls_half_final.asm.420
cls_half_final.asm.419
cls_half_final.asm.418
cls_half_final.asm.417
cls_half_final.asm.416
cls_half_final.asm.415
cls_half_final.asm.414
cls_half_final.asm.413
cls_half_final.asm.412
cls_half_final.asm.411
cls_half_final.asm.410
cls_half_final.asm.409
```

I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: `I want to keep the 3 newest files of each filename` this doesn't make sense for a windows based system? Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: Could we assume that a file that ends with "004" is newest than a file (with the same base name) ending with "003" ?

Comment: What I have done in the past is to keep the most current file as the base file, I also make a copy appending a timestamp to the filename. When I want to cleanup the files I then use it to determine how far back to keep data. This is a little different from what you are asking, but maybe it will give you an idea.

Comment: It is better to wait for a clarification from the OP. Better if this clarification is accompanied with an example of the files to be deleted and not.

Comment: The final indexnumber is assigned by the program when you save a new file as a type of backup. The variable "assembliesToBeDeleted" is the list that contains all of the files. Lets say for example that I have the following files in my array (1.asm.1, 1.asm.2, 1.asm.3, 1.asm.4, 2.asm.7, 2.asm.8, 2.asm.9, 2.asm10). The highest indexnumber would be the newest file for each base filename.

Comment: It is important to simplify a lot the things if your files have the added extension padded with zero. IE: 001, 002, 010. This will make them easily sortable in descending order

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you are looking for is:

```
File.Delete(assembly);
```

Defined: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)

So your code would end up looking like:

```
string dir = Convert.ToString(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
int asm = comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
int prt = comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1;
int drw = comboBox3.SelectedIndex + 1;
var assembliesToBeDeleted = (from a in di.GetFiles("*.asm.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                     orderby a.LastWriteTime descending, a.Name ascending
                                     select a).ToArray();
 foreach (var assembly in assembliesToBeDeleted)
 {
      File.Delete(assembly);
      Console.WriteLine(assembly);
 }
```

Comment: This will delete everything

Comment: I assumed that `assembliesToBeDeleted` were the files OP would like to delete. The question is rather confusing in parts. Hopefully OP will reword

Comment: In the variable "assembliesToBeDeleted". I would like to filter out the 3 newest files for each base filename from this array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the extension added by your backup procedure is padded to be a three character extension padding the missing numbers with zero

So having a set of files with this pattern

```
"ABCD.001"
"ABCD.002"
"ABCD.003"
"ABCD.004"
"ABCD.005"
```

you want to keep the files 003, 004, 005 then you could change your code to

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
// Get the distinct base file names of every file in that directory
// So for a bunch of files 'Name.XX1','Name.XX3','Name.XX3' we
// get an IEnumerable of only the Name part
var files = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
               .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name)).Distinct();

// Now loop over each base file name
foreach (string file in files)
{
    // Get the files with that base name in descending order but skipping the first 3
    var toDelete = di.GetFiles(file + ".*").OrderByDescending(d => d.Name).Skip(3);

    // Delete if any file is in the IEnumerable returned
    foreach(FileInfo fileToDelete in toDelete)
        fileToDelete.Delete();
}
```

If your extension are not padded with three characters then you should revert to use the LastWriteTime of the FileInfo

```
var toDelete = di.GetFiles(file + ".*").OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTime).Skip(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a filename object to hold the three parts.

```
class AssemblyFilename
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Part { get; set; }
  public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

Create a constructor to parse out the parts

```
public AssemblyFilename(string filename) { /*...*/ }
```

and then you can use LINQ

```
var fileGroups = assemblyFilenames.GroupBy(af => af.Name);
foreach(var group in fileGroups)
{
  foreach(var filenameToDelete in group.OrderByDescending(g => g.Version).Skip(3))
  {
    // delete
  }
}
```